# kafka consumer command line tool not working as expected

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using Kafka Command Line tool to consume data from a Kafka topic, but this is not working as expected.
I am using the following command :

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server totkafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost1:9092,localhost2:9092, localhost3:9092 --topic topic-name
```

and I am getting the following error stack:

```
Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.MultipleArgumentsForOptionException: Found multiple arguments for option bootstrap-server, but you asked for only one
    at joptsimple.OptionSet.valueOf(OptionSet.java:179)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$ConsumerConfig.<init>(ConsoleConsumer.scala:301)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala:52)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala)
```

May you please help me with this?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Syntax eror in your command, try below:

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost1:9092,localhost2:9092,localhost3:9092 --topic topic-name
```